# Submitting a form more than once

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

I am try to have a forum submits more then once when a user clicks the submit button. Why? I am try to add more then one idem to a shopping cart, The shopping cart software I am using doesn't support adding more then one product at a time and I don't want to edit there core code. The hidden forum would have the product ids like '1,2,3' I'd then need the JavaScript to separate the values and post each one using AJAX to the cart. I am not great a JavaScript but I coded what I think should work but its just giving me a alert: 'There was a problem with the request.' twice. I can't see whats wrong with it, any and all help and suggestions are welcomed! Here the code:

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function testResults (form) {

var product_id = form.product_id.value;
var quantity = form.quantity.value;
var brokenstring=product_id.split(",");

for ( var i in brokenstring )
{

   var http_request = false;
   function makePOSTRequest(url, parameters) {
      http_request = false;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
         http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
         if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
            // set type accordingly to anticipated content type
            //http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
            http_request.overrideMimeType('text/html');
         }
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
         try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         } catch (e) {
            try {
               http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
         }
      }
      if (!http_request) {
         alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
         return false;
      }

      http_request.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
      http_request.open('POST', url, true);
      http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
      http_request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
      http_request.send(parameters);
   }

   function alertContents() {
      if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
         if (http_request.status == 200) {
            //alert(http_request.responseText);
            result = http_request.responseText;
            document.getElementById('myspan').innerHTML = result;            
         } else {
            alert('There was a problem with the request.');
         }
      }
   }


      var poststr = "product_id=" + encodeURI( brokenstring[i] ) +
                    "&quantity=" + encodeURI( quantity );
      makePOSTRequest('post.php', poststr);



}
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="javascript:testResults(document.getElementById('myform'));" name="myform" id="myform">
<input type="text" name="product_id" id="product_id" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="1" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" />
</form>


<span name="myspan" id="myspan"></span>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: lots and lots of spelling errors making comprehension difficult. You mean form not forum right ?

Comment: idem -> item.  there -> their. Here -> Here's.

Comment: Sorry! I have been up 12+ hours, my bad spelling get a lot worse the less sleep I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add two items to the cart shouldnt you be doing two posts with the same item? I can just see one post per item there. You are not taking the quantity into account. But this is not the problem. In this case this is only a logic error.

For the javascript side I would recommend you to use jQuery to treat the ajax stuff because it will make your life WAY easier than regular javascript that might event not work with all browsers.

This is the link related to the POST method of jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Post

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't want to take quantity into account it will always be 1 but its required by that shopping cart. I don't know why I would do two posts with the same item that would put that idem it the cart twice and I want each one them once.

Answer (score 0):

It is against all the programming logics to post a form several times instead of having a more complex form. From what I can see or understand from your code you are trying to loop through your splitted (brokenstring) string. Your loop is not constructed where and how it should be. Anyway, if I were you, I would consider migraton to another free cart o the possibility to write one myself. From what I see you will be able to do so with a little bit of help from here.

Comment: is it possible to post more than once? i need to pass json in params so using post instead of get but it limits me to just one submit...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773514/pass-kendo-grid-model-in-ajax-call