# Pass kendo grid model in Ajax call

Tags: c#, json, ajax, kendo-grid

I need to pass kendo grid model (on save event) to the server side in an ajax call. How can i do that? Tried the following

```
function onSave(e) {

var keys = Object.keys(e.values);
    var colName = keys[0];
    var alignment;
    var mapHeaderId = $('#ddlMaps').val();
    var yearId = $('#ddlYear').val();

$.get("@Url.Action("CalculateFormattingForResult", "Maps")", { studentId: e.model.studentid, colId: colName, value: e.values[colName], mapHeaderId: mapHeaderId, yearId: yearId,
                                                                    model: JSON.stringify(e.model)
    }, function (data) {}
}
```

**My C# code is**

```
public string CalculateFormattingForResult(int studentId, string colId, string value, int mapHeaderId, int yearId, string model) {
}
```

If someone is interested into why i am doing that..is because i need to get the latest edited values in the grid based on which i have to calculate/update other values in the grid.

**UPDATE**

I tried it with $.post and it worked but with post the problem is that probably i can only submit the form once however, i am only doing data validation on edit event of each cell...so i need to do it again and again. so my question is still there... how do i pass json string which is [kendo dataItem (row)] in ajax??

Comment: Just a little advice, I would recommend looking into [passing an object](http://www.levibotelho.com/development/posting-javascript-objects-with-ajax-and-asp-net-mvc/) when it involves this many parameters.

Comment: Could you post the code for your grid? Also take a look at this documentation for a [javascript grid](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline) and [MVC grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-inline)

Comment: the problem is how do i pass a json string in ajax call it responds with a 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i had to put a $.post instead of $.get..found answer here:[passing json in ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729802/cant-send-json-as-string-via-ajax)

Also, as I mentioned in update, second time kendo grid model changes like this

> originaljson + edited values as json
>
> for example: **firstname:"samra", surname:"abc"** becomes **firstname:"samra", surname:"abc" , firstname:"sarah", surname:"xyz"**

In my case the newer values contained html divs (to format cells), so it was not getting posted!.